# SELECT the Min & Max from a table with the category

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I have a table with multiple columns. I need to the get min and max value from the entire table, but also display what category that min and max value are in. The column names I need are Asset_Type and Asset_Value. There are multiple (5+) asset types but I only need to show the asset type of the min value and max value.

```
SELECT Asset_Type, MAX(Asset_Value), MIN(Asset_Value) 
FROM Asset
GROUP BY Asset_Type
```

This is what I have, but this diplays the min and max for each asset type, not just the min and max for the table.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "This is what I have, but this diplays the min and max for each asset type, not just the min and max for the table."  Then remove the `Asset_Type` from the selected columns and remove the complete GROUP BY

Comment: That still doesn't work. It selects a random category, not the one assigned to the min value or the max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that max value may have different Asset_type than the min value, you need to make it separate query (not taking into account here that there might be multiple Asset_types with same min/max-value.

```
(select 'max', Asset_Type, max(Asset_Value) as 'Asset_Value'
 from Asset
 group by Asset_Type
 order by 3 desc
 limit 1)
union all
(select 'min', Asset_Type, min(Asset_Value)
 from Asset
 group by Asset_Type
 order by 3 asc
 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many asset types with the minimum value and many with the maximum value. So simply select all asset_types where the value either matches the minimum or the maximum value (which you look up in subqueries):

```
select distinct asset_value, asset_type
where asset_value = (select min(asset_value) from asset)
   or asset_value = (select max(asset_value) from asset)
order by asset_value, asset_type;
```

There are other ways to write this query, but the idea remains the same.